Leaky ReLU: Forward and backward propagation with mask and alpha
I would like to implement forward and backward propagation using Numpy by the Leaky ReLU with mask and alpha and would appreciate advice on the out and dout sections below.
If it were a simple ReLU function, these sections should show out[self.mask]=0 and dout[self.mask] = 0 and it worked.
I thought the same logic applies but below are obviously not correct.
class Leaky_ReLU():
    def __init__(self, alpha=0.01):
        self.mask = None
        self.alpha = alpha

    def __call__(self, x):
        self.mask = x <= 0
        out = x.copy()
        out[self.mask] = self.alpha 
        return out

    def backward(self, dout):
        dout[self.mask]=self.alpha
        dx = dout
        return dx


This forward pass doesn't look correct. It should be out[self.mask] *= self.alpha, not out[self.mask] = self.alpha. Setting it to a single alpha value means that its values does not vary along the range (-inf, 0], which defeats the point of a leaky ReLU.

The layer derivate should be dout[...] =1 and dout[self.mask]=self.alpha.
